# How to implement header and footer functionality in quill.js

Tags: javascript, html, printing, rich-text-editor, quill

i have a difficult and maybe odd question. I need implement the functionality of Header and Footer, like MS word does, but in this rich text editor. Someone has experience in that or can guide me with any idea?

i was thinking in create a html template for both and insert this when a button in toolbar is clicked, but my problem is, it template has to repeat in each page of the final document, how i can do that?

Thanks so much for your time.

EDIT: i forgot to mention, i work in React, but any javascript code is worth for me.

Comment: Show, what you tried.

Comment: I have not started working on this yet, I just do a deep search to analyze its feasibility and be able to talk to my boss. thanks for answering :)